# ng-click handler does not fire when clicking on a button

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I added the `data-ng-click` attribute on my button pointing to the `copy` function. However, the function does not run when I click on the button.

a.html

```
<button class="btn" data-ng-click="copy()">start</button>
```

a.js

```
$scope.copy = function() {
   console.log("aaa");
};
```

Why don't I see "aaa" in the console?

Comment: this should work if it's wired up correctly. Can you reproduce in fiddle/plunker? see this: http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/29485/

Comment: We would need to see the rest of your html to see where to are putting your app and controller in the html to make sure its correct. As Eeks33 mentioned, this looks like it should work just fine.

Comment: Do you need rest of html codes? I only asked that that case maybe happen. I need the correct answer about it.

Comment: because the basic scenario (as your code shows) does not seem to be enough to reproduce the issue so more it's needed to see if the issue is somewhere else

Answer (score 0):

I assume your button is placed in a  tag, usually **ng-submit="function()"** disables the data-ng-click event.